# pandas new dataframe based on number of occurences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I want to create a new dataframe that only contains the rows that occurred the most:

My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd

f1=pd.read_csv('FILE1.csv')
f2=pd.read_csv('FILE2.csv')
df_all = f2.merge(f1, how='left', on='Symbol')
df_sort = df_all.sort_values(by=['Symbol','Date'], ascending=[True,True])
df_sort=df_sort.dropna()
df_cnt=df_sort['Symbol'].value_counts()
```

original data from 2 files gets merged into df_all:

```
In[1]: f1

Out[2]: 
  Symbol  Weight
0    IBM     0.2
1     GE     0.3
2   AAPL     0.4
3    XOM     0.1

In[2]: f2

Out[3]: 
        Date Symbol  ClosingPrice
0   3/1/2010    IBM        116.51
1   3/2/2010    IBM        117.32
2   3/3/2010    IBM        116.40
3   3/4/2010    IBM        116.58
4   3/5/2010    IBM        117.61
5   3/1/2010     GE         45.00
6   3/2/2010     GE         43.50
7   3/3/2010     GE         46.00
8   3/1/2010   AAPL         85.07
9   3/2/2010   AAPL         85.10
10  3/3/2010   AAPL         86.20
11  3/4/2010   AAPL         84.93
12  3/5/2010   AAPL         84.80
13  3/1/2010    XOM         98.15
14  3/2/2010    XOM         99.00
15  3/3/2010    XOM         98.23
16  3/4/2010    XOM         97.56
17  3/1/2010   MSFT         99.00
18  3/2/2010   MSFT         98.00
19  3/3/2010   MSFT         97.00
20  3/4/2010   MSFT         98.00
21  3/5/2010   MSFT         97.00

In[4]:df_all

Out[4]: 
      Date     Symbol  ClosingPrice  Weight
0   3/1/2010    IBM        116.51     0.2
1   3/2/2010    IBM        117.32     0.2
2   3/3/2010    IBM        116.40     0.2
3   3/4/2010    IBM        116.58     0.2
4   3/5/2010    IBM        117.61     0.2
5   3/1/2010     GE         45.00     0.3
6   3/2/2010     GE         43.50     0.3
7   3/3/2010     GE         46.00     0.3
8   3/1/2010   AAPL         85.07     0.4
9   3/2/2010   AAPL         85.10     0.4
10  3/3/2010   AAPL         86.20     0.4
11  3/4/2010   AAPL         84.93     0.4
12  3/5/2010   AAPL         84.80     0.4
13  3/1/2010    XOM         98.15     0.1
14  3/2/2010    XOM         99.00     0.1
15  3/3/2010    XOM         98.23     0.1
16  3/4/2010    XOM         97.56     0.1
17  3/1/2010   MSFT         99.00     NaN
18  3/2/2010   MSFT         98.00     NaN
19  3/3/2010   MSFT         97.00     NaN
20  3/4/2010   MSFT         98.00     NaN
21  3/5/2010   MSFT         97.00     NaN
```

I then sort the data with the NaN values removed:

```
In[5]: df_sort

Out[5]: 
        Date Symbol  ClosingPrice  Weight
8   3/1/2010   AAPL         85.07     0.4
9   3/2/2010   AAPL         85.10     0.4
10  3/3/2010   AAPL         86.20     0.4
11  3/4/2010   AAPL         84.93     0.4
12  3/5/2010   AAPL         84.80     0.4
5   3/1/2010     GE         45.00     0.3
6   3/2/2010     GE         43.50     0.3
7   3/3/2010     GE         46.00     0.3
0   3/1/2010    IBM        116.51     0.2
1   3/2/2010    IBM        117.32     0.2
2   3/3/2010    IBM        116.40     0.2
3   3/4/2010    IBM        116.58     0.2
4   3/5/2010    IBM        117.61     0.2
13  3/1/2010    XOM         98.15     0.1
14  3/2/2010    XOM         99.00     0.1
15  3/3/2010    XOM         98.23     0.1
16  3/4/2010    XOM         97.56     0.1
```

I then determine the total number of occurrences of each Symbol

```
In[6]: df_cnt

Out[6]: 
AAPL    5
IBM     5
XOM     4
GE      3
Name: Symbol, dtype: int64
```

At this point I am stuck as to how to create a new dataframe, df_final, which contains only the data where the number of occurrences is at the max number. . . in this case 5.

My final dataframe should look like this:

```
     Date    Symbol  ClosingPrice  Weight
   3/1/2010   AAPL         85.07     0.4
   3/2/2010   AAPL         85.10     0.4
   3/3/2010   AAPL         86.20     0.4
   3/4/2010   AAPL         84.93     0.4
   3/5/2010   AAPL         84.80     0.4
   3/1/2010    IBM        116.51     0.2
   3/2/2010    IBM        117.32     0.2
   3/3/2010    IBM        116.40     0.2
   3/4/2010    IBM        116.58     0.2
   3/5/2010    IBM        117.61     0.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out the `Symbol` with maximum group size from `df_cnt` and filter rows from `df_sort`:

```
df_sort[df_sort.Symbol.isin(df_cnt.index[df_cnt == df_cnt.max()])]

#       Date    Symbol  ClosingPrice Weight
# 8 3/1/2010      AAPL         85.07    0.4
# 9 3/2/2010      AAPL         85.10    0.4
#10 3/3/2010      AAPL         86.20    0.4
#11 3/4/2010      AAPL         84.93    0.4
#12 3/5/2010      AAPL         84.80    0.4
# 0 3/1/2010       IBM        116.51    0.2
# 1 3/2/2010       IBM        117.32    0.2
# 2 3/3/2010       IBM        116.40    0.2
# 3 3/4/2010       IBM        116.58    0.2
# 4 3/5/2010       IBM        117.61    0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
 df_sort[df_sort.Symbol.isin(df_cnt[df_cnt >= df_cnt.max()].index)]
```

- `df_cnt.max()` is the maximum value of `df_cnt`.
- `df_cnt[df_cnt >= df_cnt.max()].index` is the index of all the items whose count was at least the max.
- Now just check which entries in the `Symbol` column are in the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for this purpose.

```
df_sort[df_sort['Symbol'].map(df_cnt==df_cnt.max())]

        Date Symbol  ClosingPrice  Weight
8   3/1/2010   AAPL         85.07     0.4
9   3/2/2010   AAPL         85.10     0.4
10  3/3/2010   AAPL         86.20     0.4
11  3/4/2010   AAPL         84.93     0.4
12  3/5/2010   AAPL         84.80     0.4
0   3/1/2010    IBM        116.51     0.2
1   3/2/2010    IBM        117.32     0.2
2   3/3/2010    IBM        116.40     0.2
3   3/4/2010    IBM        116.58     0.2
4   3/5/2010    IBM        117.61     0.2
```

Comment: how can i remove the index: 8,9,10,11,12,0,1 . . . .

Comment: I think you can add `.reset_index(drop=True)`at the end to reset the index to the default integer index.